# Proxy not redirecting

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, proxy

I have the following Apache config file.  When someone types in http://mywebsite.com it is not redirecting them to https.  Why?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://10.0.1.123/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://10.0.1.123/"
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.com
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mywebsite.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://10.0.1.123:80/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://10.0.1.123:80/"
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com
    ServerAdmin admin_ws1@mywebsite.com
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ... 
    ProxyPass "/" "http://10.0.1.123/"
    ...
    RewriteRule ^ https://mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

The `ProxyPass` is telling Apache to work as reverse proxy and forward the request to the real server. The `RewriteRule` instead is telling Apache to answer the request itself with a redirect to the HTTPS version of the site. Obviously it cannot do both at the same time, so there is a conflict. Please remove `Proxy*` rules and keep only the `Rewrite*` rules on port 80.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sounds obvious not that you have explained it ;)